# Python: Formatting a merged txt file

Tags: python

I want to merge two text files: names.txt and studentid.txt

the name txt contains:

```
Timmy Wong, Johnny Willis, Jason Prince
```

the studentid.txt contains:

```
B5216, B5217, B5218
```

I want to combine them into a new text file called studentlist.txt with the format I simply want all the commas to become vertical bars

```
Student_Name             Student_ID
Timmy Wong              | B5216
Johnny Willis           | B5217
Jason Prince            | B5218
```

So far I don't really know how to format this been reading up some guides and my book but it really isn't helping much.

This is what I done so far

```
def main():
    one = open( "names.txt", 'r' )
    lines = one.readlines()

    two = open( "studentid.txt", 'r' )
    lines2 = two.readlines()

    outfile = open( "studentlist.txt", 'w' )
    outfile.write( "Student_Name StudentID")
    outfile.writelines( lines + lines2 )

main()
```

and the output becomes

```
Student_Name StudentIDTimmy Wong, Johnny Willis, Jason Prince
B5216, B5217, B218
```

I'm a beginner so go easy on me ><"

Comment: You could concatenate the two files and then parse it as a CSV.

Comment: @arxanas doesn't the CSV module add the delimiter to the header line as well though? So OP would end up with `Student_Name            |Student_ID`

Comment: outfile.write( "Student_Name StudentID") --> I think you need to add a `\n` at the end to get a new line.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
with open('data.txt') as f1,open('data1.txt') as f2,open('sudentlist.txt') as f3:

    line=f1.readline().strip()             #read the first line of names file 
    names=map(str.strip,line.split(','))   #split the line by "," and then apply strip()

    line=f2.readline().strip()             #read the first line of ID file 
    ids=map(str.strip,line.split(','))     #split the line by "," and then apply strip()

    f3.write("{0:25}{1}\m".format("Student_Name","Student_Id"))

    for name,i in zip(names,ids):          #use zip() to fetch data from both lists
        f3.write("{0:25}|{1}\n".format(name,i)) #use write() instead of print to write it to a file
```

**output:**

```
Student_Name             Student_Id
Timmy Wong               |B5216
Johnny Willis            |B5217
Jason Prince             |B5218
```

Comment: Mmm how do i output that into studentlist.txt? do i use .strip() at the end if I want to read more then just the first line?

Comment: Nice I understand now ^_^ so say I put more names and under will be another line with the name Jimmy Ly and the ID is  B5219 on the 2nd line in txt how would I do that?

Is it f1.readlines() ?

Comment: @JimmyLy 2nd line of which file?

Comment: Actually nvm I got it I used f1.read() and it read more then the first line of names in the file. thank you without you I'll be struggling all night lol xD

btw can you explain what does ("{0:25}|{1}\n".format(name,i)) do? and how does it work? I can't find it in my lecture slides or book

Comment: @JimmyLy I used `format()` here over the old `"%s"` based formatting, here 25 is the width of the first field, you can read more [`format() here`](http://docs.python.org/library/string.html#formatspec)

Answer (score 4):

```
names = [n.strip() for n in open("names.txt").read().split(",")]
ids = [i.strip() for i in open("studentid.txt").read().split(",")]

print "Student_Name\t| Student_ID"
for n, i in zip(names, ids):
    print "{}\t| {}".format(n, i)
```

Answer (score 0):

Untested, but you want something similar to:

```
import csv
with open('names.txt') as nf, open('studentid.txt') as sf, open('output.txt','wb') as pf:
    csvnf = csv.reader(nf)
    csvsf = csv.reader(sf)
    csvpf = csv.writer(pf, delimiter='|')
    for name_student in zip(csvnf, csvsf):
        pf.writerow( name_student )
```

Answer (score 0):

```
names       = [n.strip() for n in open("names.txt").read().split(",")]
student_ids = [i.strip() for i in open("studentid.txt").read().split(",")]

outfile = open("studentlist.txt", 'w')
outfile.write("Student_Name\tStudent_ID\n")

for current_name, current_id in zip(names, student_ids):
    outfile.write(current_name + "\t|" + current_id + "\n")

outfile.close()
```